# Xcode "valid signing identity not found" on new Computer

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I was working perfectly fine last week and somehow the HD was damaged, I bought a new one and everything ok... Then I install xcode and download some certificates for my app, app developer, etc... And when I plug my iPod touch in the iPod provisioning Profiles i get the message "Valid signing identity not found". What can I do to restore everything back to normal?

Comment: did you also add your certificates into your keychain? the provisioning profiles go into xcode, the developer / distribution certificates go into the keychain.

Comment: yes, that was the first thing done after I downloaded them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the private keys that were used to sign the certificate. If you don't have them anymore you can generate a new signing request on the dev page.

Comment: thanks I had to delete all the certificates and re-make them... thanks a lot

Comment: In my case I'm trying to use two computers both using the same profile. After I import private key from key chain of one computer to another, the message "Valid signing identity not found" disappears.