# Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios-provisioning

I think I've reached the nadir of `iOS` provisioning hell. After migrating to a new mac and doing an archive for distribution, I received the error:

> Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain
>   any of the keychain's signing certificates

I then erased all certs and keys and provision profiles and did a "hard reset" (deleting all keys, certs, and profiles), following Apple's instructions by hand, with the same error. Then I did another hard reset and then had Xcode handle the whole thing via the Organizer, did another archive - only to see the same error.

I have all certs (`WDRCA`, `Developer ID Cert Authority`, `iPhone Dev`, `iPhone Distribution`) showing in Keychain Access, `Xcode` shows that it sees the dev and distribution certs, as well as the provisioning profiles, all marked with a green checkmark and "valid" status.

Code signing within the app show the correct dev and distribution is selected.

What's really troubling is that a Google search on the error shows [one tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) from Apple that isn't very helpful, 2 tweets, and 3 results in Japanese - and nothing else. I contacted one of the tweeps and he said he fixed it with a hard result, which I have done twice.

Any ideas on where to go or what to do next?

Comment: I ran into this problem when moving machines, fixed by following steps at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After nine hours of hair pulling, cursing and burying my head in my hands... All I had to do was create a new project, transfer the files over by hand, and the error went away. Argh.

**Update**: My marking my own answer as correct does not mean these other answers were wrong - I didn't get a chance to try any of them.

Answer (score 27):

Fixed it by Organizer -> Teams (select Your Team) -> Refresh (low right corner).

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: Organizer is button top right of xcode, opposite end to the run button.  Teams is under the Devices Tab at top

Comment: Fixed it by changing Build Settings -> Bundle Identifier

Comment: @Jon I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and couldn't find any button called "Organizer".  Have it changed place in this version, or how does it look like? Does it open the same window as going to menu Window > Organizer?

Answer (score 10):

After removing all `devices/profiles/certificates` and `adding/creating` it did still not work here too....also removing the Xcode prefs did not help.

but it seems to in the project settings, check in the build settings under `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITIY`, in my project the first line was set to a old profile but not visible in the list, only if you open the pulldown, after removing that it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem as well. I finally realized that the identifier is case sensitive. For example if your product name is "StackOverflow" it automatically tags the identifier with com.yourcompanyname.StackOverflow. (this of course can be changed by going to the summary of the target). The problem lies in what the app id is in the developer portal. Make sure that the identifier in the portal matches what's in Xcode.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that app ids are definitely case sensitive (at least for iOS). My original app id was 'com.companyName.appName'. Changing it to 'com.companyName.AppName' and regenerating certificates and provisioning profiles worked.

Comment: Damn! That was it - mismatch in bundle name!  thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue here since Xcode 4.3 install (moving from /Developer to /Applications). I found [this post](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/02/02/switching-the-xcode-path-using-xcode-select/) for changing the Xcode dir

in the terminal check what path it is set to with:

`/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path`

and then if it is still set to `/Developer` set it to `/Applications`:

`sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications`

which worked for me to be able to do the update to 4.3.2 but this did not resolve the issue mentioned....so maybe it helps you.

Comment: you solution could have worked as well. I would have posted my answer sooner but SO made me wait 8 hours to answer my own question... Now I have to wait till tomorrow to accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

i 've  met the same problem.

the answer of the problem is simple.

you need to login your apple develpoer web site 
to apply and download a profile for your app .

after double-click the download file , 
you can see the file in organization of the project in xcode .

the name of the bundle id is the type like com.yourname.appname

the xcode device choose the ios device
and the codesign of the target should choose distribution 
which is one of the file in organization of the project in xcode .

f.y.i.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after upgrading to `Xcode 4.3.2` and `SDK 5.1`. Everything worked perfectly in the previously version of `Xcode` with `SDK 5.0`. After many hours of hair pulling I created a new distribution certificate in the `iOS Provisioning Portal->Provisioning-> Distribution Tab` and after downloading it and installing it into `Xcode` (drag-and-drop) it works to archive after selecting the new certificate in the `Code Signing area` for my target.

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I had exactly the same problem.

The issue is related to no having the correct distribution provisioning profiles; My error was that I added a new device to the portal and did not re-download the distribution profile from the developer site.

Today I had the same issue; while it was working perfectly with the developer profile i could not archive or build a distribution package..

I had to go to the portal and manually re-download my distribution profile because new hardware was added even though I am not actively using it on the developer profile (did not check the box to add it to the provision)

Hope it helps anyone

Comment: I think my problem was quite alike. In my case it was sufficient to go to the Organizer -> select "Devices" -> select "Library>Provisioning profiles" on the left hand side and click "refresh" (bottom right)

Answer (score 1):

I went straight to "but it seems to in the project settings, check in the build settings under CODE_SIGN_IDENTITIY, in my project the first line was set to a old profile but not visible in the list, only if you open the pulldown, after removing that it worked."

And that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by updating the bundle identifier in the project settings > targets > appName
in the info tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and fixed it by putting my scheme back to Debug, as opposed to Release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading the OS/xcode so its worth to try.
the solution for me was simple,
go to the ios provisioning portal.
make sure the app certificate for the app is valid and not expired.
download again it again and double click it to install.
it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to build a release version - no problem occurred for debug builds. Baffling because in the code signing section of the build settings I had the same profile selected.

The solution for me was to create and download a new distribution provisioning profile, even though from the settings it appears not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that was not on here, after looking through the errors and looking into my raw .app file, i found the solution.

Go to your target, and then "Build Phases" instead of Build Settings.

Make sure that in "Compile Sources" is your storyboard.  For some reason Xcode didn't add the storyboard to this area of my file when I coppied the storyboard in.

P.S. I had to add the other .m's that i wanted in the project to this area as well (the ones that I dragged in, not created in the project)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Target settings, in Sumary, check if Bundle Identifier is exactly the same as in itunesconnect.com

as example:

Bundle ID: com.mycompany.myapplication

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by Analysing instead and checking that error. It indicated that my bundle ID was not lowercase as in the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was having this issue but whenever I tried to get into the organiser it caused XCode to crash.  To resolve this issue I went into my targets and changed everything under Code Signing Identity to iPhone Developer.  The target defaulted to the provisioning profile I wanted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to choose "Don't code sign" and then do a build.  This generates an error, but seems to clear out whatever xcode is hanging on to.  Then choose the right provisioning profile and build.  This has solved similar problems for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.
Went to Project-> general-> found an option "no provisioning profiles found" Fix Issue button. Clicked it . Automatically fixed

Answer (score 0):

**Reason Of Error**

If you don't have any valid provisioning profile downloaded to your system's **Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles** folder then you might run into this error.

**Solution**

Login to your Apple Developer Account from Xcode->Preferences->Accounts and then download a valid provisioning profile.

Move to Target->General and select the correct Team.

Now go to Project Build Settings->Code Signing Identity and select just '**iOS Developer**' and '**Automatic**' in Provisioning Profiles. Your app will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

In the Build Settings look for

General > Identity > Bundle Identifier and Team Settings. Fill in the Bundle Identifier and select Team. (this basically your publishing info). Of course as the others have written you'll need the correct dev or team account. This solution worked for me and resolved the build error.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the SUDO permission you have given while adding the platform.

Follow this link [Ionic Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2015/11/ionic-invalid-device-state-error-with-xcode-7-solved)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.