# "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any ..." error in xcode 4.3.2 Distribution certificate

Tags: ios5, certificate, distribution

Experts!

Few days ago i was using previous version of xcode. That time my Distribution certificate worked fine. But now I am using xcode 4.3.2 I got new problem Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates.

Also i try all conditions from URL [Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982788/code-sign-error-no-unexpired-provisioning-profiles-found-that-contain-any-of-th/10054207#10054207)

And this certificate is valid.. I it Checked by Key Chain Access. 
Please anyone send me the correct answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problems myself..
Here First of all I revoke my distribution certificates. 
After i created App ID which is suitable for my app bundle id, 
Then i created another distribution certificate which contain my app id with bundle id
For example :Players-com.NevproBusinessSolutions.my_app
After this I downloaded that certificate. And Open with iPhone configure also with xcode.
Then I checked in code_in_sighning.. There I found mu Distribution certificate.
select that one and build and run my app without error.
:)
So I able to upload my app in app store by App loader