# No identities are available for signing - publishing app in xcode

Tags: xcode, distribution, archive, keychain

I'm fighting with this problem for two days. 
I've finished my app in `xcode 4.6`, I created the app on `Itunes Connect` and the status is `Waiting For Upload`. I've also all the certificates (developer and Distribution) and in `Distribution Provisioning Profiles` I have my profiles.

[LINK](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3537/schermatamac.jpg)

In `xcode` I create the archive by the comand `Product -> Archive` and everything goes ok. But when I click on `validate` or `Submit` an error message comes out:  `No identities are available for signing`  (in my Keychain everything is ok).

[LINK](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/7965/schermata032456359alle0.png)

Even if I press `Download Identities` nothing happens.

I have no idea how to fix the problem. I have spent two days looking for solutions here and in other forums, following the instructions, but I have not found anything...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you completed the code signing section?

If you select your project name from the top of the inspector on the left of Xcode, click `Build Settings` than find the `Code Signing` section:

[image]

Comment: this is what i see:
[link](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8743/schermata032456359alle1.png)

Comment: OK, well where it says `Don't Code sign` you need to assign the relevant provisioning profile.

Comment: ok now I have this [LINK](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/schermata032456359alle1.png/)
but when I click "Archive" an error comes out:
"No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"

Comment: Sounds like you're getting closer. Have a look here for tips on that error message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091590/no-unexpired-provisioning-profiles-found-that-contain-any-of-the-keychains-sig