# getting error when provisioning in xcode

Tags: ios, provisioning

What I am having in `Provisioning` of the account is 
[image]

Then I am downloading both of them and drag into Organizer/Library/Provisioning Profile. However, I am always getting these status

[image]

What I am missing in the middle..Please advice on this issue.

Comment: Did you download those on a new machine?

Comment: what I was downloading are 1.WWDR 2.Development Certificates 3.Those two above

Comment: Your development certificate are associated with a public and private key present on your machine - are u sure you have those on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs when your private keys for your iOS development certificates are absent on your machine. This occurs for example if you have installed XCode on a new machine.

Apple provide steps by steps instruction [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_FAQ-WHAT_DOES__VALID_SIGNING_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND__MEAN_AND_HOW_DO_I_RESOLVE_IT_) for this kind of error.

This issue has been resolved already on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a) where you will see you have two possible solutions:

- The easiest consist to transfer your development profile from your old machine to your new one.
- Revoke and generate a new development profile by generating a new Certificate request with Keychain