# Code Sign error:org.apache.cordova.cordovalibapptests.CordovaLibApp' error in Xcode4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, xcode4.3

Am new to phonegap. NOw am working in phonegap2.0 in Xcode4.3. I have installed phonegap2.0 in my lion mac. Now I have followed this below link:

```
"http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera"
```

for creating camera in phonegap(Phonegap API'S). Now the Phonegap Api's are working in Simulatore5. But when run the coding via Ipod device. It is shows this below error:

```
"Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'org.apache.cordova.cordovalibapptests.CordovaLibApp' could not be found"
```

Could anybody please help me to solve this issue?.
[image]
I have attach the Screen Shot for the error page.

Comment: This will explain you what to do: [Xcode 4 - "Valid signing identity not found" error on provisioning profiles on a new Macintosh install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a). Next time is it quicker to search before you ask. This question was asked many time before.