# 3rd Party Mac Developer doesn't match any valid, non-expired private key pairs?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I just cloned [this repo](https://github.com/kgn/Spectttator) from github and would like to have a play with it. However, in XCode, I keep getting the following error:

`The identity '3rd Party Mac Developer Application' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains`

It's worth noting that in my Build Settings, I've set the *Code Signing Identity* property to **Don't Code Sign**, but I'm still getting this error.

Has anyone ever encountered this, and if so, what did you do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: if your process of making build is correct, then try cleaning the app or delete the .app file created in /Library/iPhone Simulator directory and build again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have downloaded the project and noticed that there are 2 Xcode projects:

- SpectttatorTest.xcodeproj,
- Spectttator.xcodeproj.

The first one has set "Code Signing Identity" to "Don't Code Sign", but the second project (which is embedded in the first as a dependency) has set "Code Signing Identity" to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application".

After setting "Don't Code Sign" for the second project no code signing error occurred anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Ater changing the setting, if you notice the same thing happening with your own projects, it may be time to get a new certificate. It's what I had to do last July.

**EDIT:**

If indeed that's what you have to do, [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a) contains an answer describing the procedure for moving forward.