# testing App on device "valid signing identity not found"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, testing, device

I´m currently developing an app for my university. And I´d like to test it on my device. The problem is, my provisioning profile can´t find a valid signing identity. And in TEAMS it says: "Unable to code sign using identities in this team: no valid certificates with private keys found".

I have tried various solutions that I found here, but they didn´t work for me.

My special problem is: I don´t get an Apple developer account, or access too the apple developer website. I got an Apple Certifcate and an Provisioning Profile in an e-mail. I added the Certificate to the keychain and the profile in Xcode. Is it even possible to test it without access to the developer account? And how?

I´d be really grateful for any solution!

Comment: Yeah you can I think you either wrong certificate or you are wrong name in info.plist.please see it.

Comment: invoke your certificate and create new certificate after this Create provisioning profile using new certificate for your App and install it provisioning profile and set Properly

Comment: I think You need the private keys that were used to sign the certificate

Comment: check whether your project's bundle identifier and bundle identifier used in the App Id is same or not

Comment: @NitinGohel-He already said that"My special problem is: I don´t get an Apple developer account, or access too the apple developer website."

Comment: You need the private key. If they didn't give you the private key along with the certificate, you can't sign apps.

Comment: OK thanks i will ask for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the private key that is generated when you create the development certificate. (This private key is called p12 certificate)

Comment: This. It sounds like the OP wasn't given the private key along with the certificate.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Just to be certain: I need a 3rd file? a private key? And I add it to keys in the keychain?

Comment: Yes you must add the private key to the keychain. Please let me know if the issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will ask at my university and post the result here.

Comment: I now got an exported version of the developerprofile of the macbook it was created on and it works. Thank you so much for you help everybody!

Comment: @Philipp Lechner, You have to click on checkmark if it has resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To test on your device you need a valid provisioning profile with the related certificate and the iPhone must be provisioned in that provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a new mac? in that case you have to copy the certificate reference from your old mac. I had this problem and it was work with the certificate, check them out in keys

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is add private key(p12 certificate) to your keychanin. I think this link will solve your problem.As the author described it very nicely..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8509545/1865424

still have issue.please let me know..

Enjoy..