# Iphone app archive the provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain, provisioning-profile

Can I use the others `provisioning profile` certificate to `Archive` the code. If any active `provisioning profile` is there in the developer account. Can i simply download it and used to archive the code?

I downloaded but getting the error `valid signing identity not found`.

What else do I need to do with the keychain certificate and the other private key and how to do that?

Comment: I hope this will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a?rq=1

Comment: this thing will work when you have .p12 file to import to other thing..but i dont have that .p12 to export

Answer (score 0):

No.... you can not use the provision profile in this way. you must have to install the valid certificate for that provision profile.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to check the bundle identifier of your project.bundle identifier of your project is same as provisioning profile bundle identifier..**

Answer (score 0):

1. Each App should have it's unique AppId (usualy it is reverse DNS such as com.apple.sampleapp).
2. Each developer has it's own developer certificate, that identifies him.
3. Each device has its own Unique Device ID (UDID)

Provisioning profile binds this 3 things together:
 - it includes list of developers, who can use this profile
 - it includes list of devices, where apps built with this profile can be installed(for distribution its different)
 - it specifies application (or using '*' many applications) which could be built using   this profile.

So, based on this, in order to use provisioning profile you need to have valid sertificate included in profile and installed on your machine, you need your device UDID to be included in profile, you need your app id adhere profile bundle id.

Comment: I dont have the .p12 to get into my system...so i can i use certificate or any other way