# code signing Identity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a problem like "Code Signing Identity" when installing a distribution profile on our Mac. This Profile is created by my client. I download this from the client's Apple developer account. Please help me.

Comment: You need the certificate and private key as well, from your client.  You can get the certificate from their developer account too but you can only get the private key from them directly.

Comment: you need .p12 file that has private key.

Comment: Hey suraj what is process of geting .p12 file ,can specify more plz...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 - "Valid signing identity not found" error on provisioning profiles on a new Macintosh install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a)

Comment: Hey Borrrden I do like that but issue have.

Comment: Hey any one their?????

Comment: you should ask to your client.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up what the others are saying, in order to use your client's distribution provisioning profile you need to have them export the private key / certificate pair that was used in the portal CSR process. The portal certificates are tied to the box that created & completed theDev Portal's CSR process and subsequently the provisioning profiles are associated with the certificates existing in the portal.

Long story short: have your client export their private key / certificate tied to the distribution profile from Keychain Access (note: they won't always do this).