# Exception: Valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I have an issue in adding provisioning file to Xcode. After creating and uploading provisioning file to Xcode, it says; "**Valid signing identity not found**".

Can someone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You have to check below points:

1. Is bundleIdentifier used is same as that in developer account.
2. Is the device on which you are testing is added in the provisioning profile in your developer account.
3. Is your developer certificate right.

Also you can check below URL:

[Xcode 4 - "Valid signing identity not found" error on provisioning profiles on a new Macintosh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a)