# Error while uploading a new version to apple store in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to upload a new version to the apple store but in my app general setting in my xcode 8 objective c, it gives me error in provisioning profile. Can you help [image]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 - "Valid signing identity not found" error on provisioning profiles on a new Macintosh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a)

Comment: These guides may help you, part 1: https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1
part 2: https://www.raywenderlich.com/127939/submit-an-app-part-2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by only connecting the Xcode with real device!